# JavaFX - IDE and executable jar performance

Tags: performance, jar, javafx, executable

I have used both NetBeans and Intellij to generate new HelloWorld JavaFX projects using Java 7_21. It runs successfully in both IDE's and, most importantly, in both cases inside the IDE, the application executes almost instantly. I then create an executable jar from each project. It successfully creates the jar and when I run it (either by double clicking on it or from the command line) it runs correctly but takes about 10 seconds to execute in both cases. At the command prompt I enter "java -version" and it confirms I am running Java 7_21 64bit. Does anyone happen to know why the executable jar runs so slowly while in the IDE's the HelloWorld applications runs so quickly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [JavaFX Deployment troubleshooting guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/troubleshooting.htm#A1215576):

> If your application starts slow, then it could be due to network configuration. Try disabling the autoproxy configuration by passing `-Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true` to see if it helps.

Comment: But one does ponder why a standalone java application on a single machine is affected by a network configuration?

Comment: @yorkville, I only know how to fix the slow startup issue, not why it is so.